# Getting search suggestions to work on 2 (or more) non-consecutive words (to improve search on a medical conditions list - ICD10 codes)

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

Context:

- We are using Azure Cognitive Services in a mobile app to search patient diagnostic codes (ICD10 codes).
- The ICD10 code list is approximately 94,000 items. For anyone interested here is a [list](https://github.com/Bobrovskiy/ICD-10-CSV/tree/master/2020).
- We currently have set-up a standard Lucene analyser on the diagnostic description field

Requirement:

- We want to provide a really good **search as you type** experience, which provides the most relevant suggestions
- Using the `Suggest` method with the `fuzzy` parameter set to `true` works reasonably well for a **single** search term:

  - [image]
- As you can see it does well in finding *partial* matches **and** is resilient to *typos*.
- The issue comes in when I add a second search term.  E.g. I want to search for `asthma` that is `moderate`:

  - [image]
  - [image]
- In both these examples, there is no match.
- So when searching for more than one term, requiring the user to express this in the sequence that this is in the data is not a good user experience.
- Using the `Search` method instead, we can overcome the problem of finding matches where 2 search terms are supplied that do not appear consecutively in the data:

  - [image]
- And this is resilient to typos
- **However**, this is not good at finding partial matches (like the `Suggest` does).
- E.g. in this search, we would still want the term `moderate` to be picked up:
  [image]
- Seemingly if we could combine a wild card search with a fuzzy search we could solve this problem. e.g. supplying the following search phrase: `ashtma~* AND moder~*`.
- But from what we have seen this syntax is not supported.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this limitation so we can get the best of both worlds, i.e:

- For 2 or more search terms, it will work on *partial* matches
- And the search terms are treated independently and do not need to appear consecutively in the data

Many thanks in advance,
Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using (or at least experimenting with) Lucene ngrams.

An example custom analyzer can use the [`NGramTokenFilter`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00016/api/analysis-common/Lucene.Net.Analysis.NGram.NGramTokenFilter.html).

This filter splits each source token into one or more indexed tokens by chopping up the source into substrings of different lengths.

An example from the above link:

> "abc" will give "a", "ab", "abc", "b", "bc", "c"

You can, as an example, set each token to be from 3 to 5 characters long (but this is one of the areas where you can experiment with different settings).

When you use this analyzer for indexing, it's going to create many more tokens (larger index) but that gives you more searching flexibility.

---

Use the same analyzer for searching.

If the user enters the following two words as their search values:

```
ashtma moder
```

You would convert that into the following Lucene search phrase:

```
ashtma~ AND moder~
```

This will find the following hits:

```
  doc id = 12877
  field  = Moderate persistent asthma with status asthmaticus

  doc id = 12874
  field  = Moderate persistent asthma

  doc id = 12875
  field  = Moderate persistent asthma, uncomplicated

  doc id = 12876
  field  = Moderate persistent asthma with (acute) exacerbation

  doc id = 94210
  field  = Family history of asthma and oth chronic lower resp diseases

  doc id = 6970
  field  = Xanthelasma of right lower eyelid

  doc id = 6973
  field  = Xanthelasma of left lower eyelid

  doc id = 6979
  field  = Chloasma of right lower eyelid and periocular area

  doc id = 6982
  field  = Chloasma of left lower eyelid and periocular area
```

As you can see it does find some false positives, but the first four hits (the highest scored) are the ones you want.

You can see how this approach performs in terms of index size and search speed.

One reason for suggesting ngrams is your point about wanting to handle mis-spellings: ngrams may help to isolate spelling mistakes into smaller tokens,since the `~` fuzzy search operator is fairly limited in what it can handle. But, definitely experiment with different ngram lengths - and maybe also without using ngrams at all.

Comment: Thanks very much for this @andrewJames.  You have put a lot of considered effort in your response.  I am fumbling my way implementing / trialing this, as I am very new to Azure Cognitive Search.  Turns out good search is very hard to get right!

Comment: Yes indeed, understood. My answer is fairly generic (it's based on pure-Lucene). You may get a more focused/useful answer if you ask a brand new and more specific Azure Cognitive Search question, showing the relevant code - and maybe your attempt to use ngrams in that code. Someone may also show you a better way. (I don't use Azure Cognitive Search myself.)